# Can a recursive function have knowledge of a constant in the function in which it was first called without sending it the constant as a parameter?

Tags: c++, recursion

Because recursion has the added overhead of pushing and popping activation records, is it possible to avoid this when it comes to using constants?

For example if I have a function

```
void foo(int x) {
   int bar = x;
   fooAux(root);
}

fooAux(Root * root) {
   // Can I somehow do something with the variable bar here?
   // {Insert recursive code}
}
```

I'm not sure if there's any way other than passing bar into the recursive function but this seems unnecessary as I am certain that its value is not meant to change? Maybe passing by reference could ease the matter? Thoughts, please.

Comment: Probably not the most important performance issue to worry about.

Comment: How about adding another argument to `fooAux()`?

Comment: @H2CO3: That works, but it's the solution the OP is specifically trying to avoid.

Comment: @user2357112 I doubt that would cause any noticeable performance loss.

Comment: You could use a file-scope variable.  But, that's incredibly bad style.

Comment: *Can a recursive function have knowledge of a constant in the function in which it was first called without sending it the constant as a parameter?* No. And `bar` is not a constant in your example, it's a variable.

Comment: @H2CO3: Me too, hence my first comment.

Comment: @m0skit0: It's constant within the context of one function call, though. I'm pretty sure you could declare it `const` without a problem.

Comment: Is it OK if the not-a-constant in the code is made into a constant?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about it not being constant. Thanks for the comments. I'm not sure exactly how this would impact performance because the tests I'm running are small right now. I'll just pass it as a reference then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not very clear, referring to a "constant" in the title, but then in the code example using a variable.

Anyway the answer is "yes", a recursive helper function can easily refer to a constant or variable in a non-recursive caller function, as long as thread-safety is not a concern.

All you need to do is declare the variable `static`:

```
struct Whatever {};

void foo( int x )
{
    static int bar;

    struct Aux 
    {
        static void foo( Whatever )
        {
            (void) bar;
        }
    };

    bar = x;
    Aux::foo( Whatever() );
}
```

---

Is this a good idea? No, it smells of **premature optimization**. The speed gain, if any, would be marginal, while the maintenance cost could be high.

Comment: To back up this being a not-good idea: as well as premature optimization it smells of being non-reentrant (which makes it both non-thread-safe as you mentioned *and also* non-signal-safe).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a global variable, e.g: `g_bar`.
However, this makes your function neither reentrant or elegant.

You can also create a separate struct consisting of the two functions above and a `bar` member variable, it would be a nice example of premature optimization of the devil.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you question is not primarily about recursion, but about scoping. Maybe you could also live with an answer to: *Can a function access a variable which is not passed as a parameter (nor defined locally)*

The answer this this question is "yes". There are several options:

- A function can have access to global variables. In many cases this is an anti-pattern and not exactly what you are looking for.
- There is a very interesting concept of a *closure*, which comes very close to what you are looking for. It allows a function to access an "environemnt" in which your `bar` variable could live.

However, there are no closures in C++ and I am not aware of any elegant way of mimicking closures in C++. Also closures where invented for semantic reasons (it gives programmers more power), not for performance reasons.

Comment: "there are no closures in C++" -- that's harsh on C++11 lambdas. They're not "proper" closures since they don't extend the life of the variables they capture (so you can't for example return a capturing lambda from the function it's defined in, which some/many languages allow). But they are a kind of closure.